# Linking to another region in the same page?

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation, theming

My page is broken down into region-a and region-b, region-a links to several Drupal nodes. When I click the links I want the nodes to display in region-b and not in a new page. Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible. You can use AJAX to intercept the on-click event on your links in region-a and asynchronously load the content into , for example <div id="region-b"></div>.

Comment: Thanks, Triskelion... would that also work in a view? Like if the links in region-a are generated by a view?

Comment: A link is a link, however you create it.